# ddrescue said most of sectors are good but I only got 20% files restored

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

One of my hdd broke down and I tried to use ddrescue to make an image and rescue my files.

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r2 /dev/sda4 ~/tmp/test.img ~/test.logfile
```

(I don't have enough space on my linux laptop, so I mounted ~/tmp/ to a Windows samba server, win7 actually)

It finished in more than 16 hours, and I got a 930G image file (same size as sda4). I use ddrescueview to check and get this.

[image: ddrescueview info]

Looks like most of the data is fine(?)

But when I used ext2explore to extract files on Windows, there are only 180G files there.

Lots of files are not in the image file.

Is this right? or something went wrong?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1090647/432690

Comment: Can you explain exactly what type of file system did you image? If you use `ext2explore` then it's ext2/3 I suppose. Did you try to mount it under linux? Some live from usb even.

Comment: ext4. I use ext2explore-2.2.71 (but it still says it's 2.1 in 'about')(https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/). It says it supports ext4. I didn't try to mount it under linux because it's too large and get stuck when mount it through samba.

Comment: @tansy Oh I just tried to mount it under linux and it didn't cost much time this time. There are more files I can see and read. But I don't want to restore then through network. (Image is on Windows, and mounted on my linux laptop through samba, and I just want to restore file on the same windows too). Are there any better ways to do this? I checked yesterday but didn't find a useful tool but ext2explore.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Ext2Fsd Project](https://www.ext2fsd.com/) @ [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) that works under windows. I was using it before and it was fine.
Here is a [howto](https://www.techgainer.com/how-to-mount-and-access-linux-partitions-ext4ext3ext2-in-windows-explorer-easily/) use it.

--

It can be done this way, if someone is still interested: (assume `\>` is DOS command prompt)
Install [Ext2Fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/):

According to readme you are to specify system and architecture or use `install` option for auto. `\> Setup.bat` without parameters will show help.

```
\> cmd
\> cd %Ext2Fsd-install-dir%
...\Ext2Fsd\Setup \> Setup.bat wxp i386
```

Then install [imdisk](http://ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) so you are able to mount all kinds of images. I chose this one as it is simple, reliable works like a charm on every windows I tried (win:xp/7/10; @ x86/x64) and has command line interface along with GUI.
Now mount your image as drive:

```
\> cd %image-dir%
\> imdisk -a -o fix -m V: -f 001.ext3
```

That's it. You have successfully mounted linux partition image under windows. If you don't like CLI you can do it in GUI, will do the same job.